# saving JSON string in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am trying to save a JSON string to the database.

this is the error that I get:

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

And this is how my JSON looks like:

```
"metadata": {
      "is_ivr": 0,
      "is_upgradable": 1,
      "is_sms": 0,
      "is_design": 0,
      "threshold_amount": 0,
      "post_threshold": 0,
      "pre_threshold": 0
    }
```

I want to save the value of metadata as string.

I tried doing this:

```
$data = $request->input('data');
$data['metadata'] = json_encode($data['metadata']);
```

Result of `dd($data);`

```
array:8 [
  "product_name" => "Pulse"
  "parent_product" => 0
  "product_description" => "goes here"
  "metadata" => array:7 [
    "is_ivr" => 0
    "is_upgradable" => 1
    "is_sms" => 0
    "is_design" => 0
    "threshold_amount" => 0
    "post_threshold" => 0
    "pre_threshold" => 0
  ]
  "price_period" => 1
  "price_variation" => 2
  "outlet_pricing" => 0
  "status" => 1
  ]
]
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is in here? Show the whole code and result of `dd($data);` Do you use Eloquent? for creating record? And what version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: why encode and not decode?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek  I am using Laravel 5.1. Yes, using Eloquent for creating record. I have added the result of dd($data);

Answer (score 7):

To be honest I don't know what's going on at the moment, but open your model (I don't know its name because you haven't showed it) and fill:

```
protected $casts = [
    'metadata' => 'array',
];
```

assuming you haven't done it yet.

Now, when you insert data into database don't use any `json_encode`, simply you can use:

```
$data = $request->input('data');
```

without:

```
$data['metadata'] = json_encode($data['metadata']);
```

Using `casts` property Laravel will automatically convert array data to json when inserting into database and automatically run `json_decode` to get array when getting data from database.

Comment: I'll try this in a while after I go to office.

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize your data before save the JSON into the DB for example:

```
$data = serialize( json_encode( $data['metadata'] ) );
// Insert $data into the DB
```

Now if you want to reuse the data in PHP from the DB you need to run the opposite unserialize.

```
$raw_data = // query to get the data from the DB
$data = unserialize( $raw_data );
```

This will allow you to save data structures such as arrays. [From the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

> Generates a storable representation of a value.

Answer (score 0):

use `Implode();`  and separate it by commas or if you would like you can access the property of the array by calling its index directly `$data['metadata'][index]`

whats happening is you are calling a regex on an array not a value.